# Unable to use gpu for model training yet tensorflow is using the gpu

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

```
I've been encountering an issue while working with TensorFlow GPU version 2.9.0 after configuring CUDA 11.6, ensuring compatibility with cuDNN, and setting up the necessary environment variables. Initially, I ran a code snippet to check if my GPU was detected:
import tensorflow as tf
```

print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
The output confirmed the GPU was recognized.

```
However, when I attempted to train my model using the GPU, I encountered a "resources exhausted" error. Upon checking the Task Manager, I noticed that the system was still primarily utilizing CPU RAM, neglecting the GPU.
```

Here are the images for reference:
[GPU configured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nzfy.jpg)
[Resources usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgxZO.jpg)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LETF.jpg)

I'd greatly appreciate any insights or solutions to understand why the GPU is recognized but not utilized during model training. Any help on this matter would be highly valuable!

Comment: Your GPU has only 4 GB of RAM, that is very little, maybe not enough for the model you are training, also you did not say what model you were training.

Answer (score 0):

You give very little information about the NN you want to train, so a precise analysis is not possible. However, "resources exhausted" gives you a strong hint, that the GPU memory is expired. Furthermore, that fact that the error happens before allocation shows you that more memory is needed. As the check for memory allocation failed and it was not even allocated, you can not see the use of the GPU in the task manager.

As the tensor of shape 128,128,32,32 caused the problem, its size has to be reduced. If one of the dimensions corresponds to the batch_size, I would highly suggest to reduce this quantity first. Again, for a more in depth analysis, more informations about your code are required.

Comment: My model is about GANs, and i was just trying to test whether the cuda is working or not, so that i could run it on nvidia A6000 with 256 gb RAM, where primarily it is using cpu RAM but not GPU

Comment: 1. "My model is about GANs" is a rather unprecise information. Can you give the number of parameters of you model and the batch size, please. Without this information, a proper debugging is not possible.
2. As far as I am aware, the nvidia RTX A6000 provides 48 GB of memory, which can be doubled to 96 GB via NV-Link, but does not provided 256 GB.
3. From your screenshot it can be seen that your system has 4 GB of graphics memory. If this is not sufficient for the model, then you can not test it.